# How do I initiate the DLC missions in Saints Row 4?

Tags: saints-row-iv, saints-row-iv-saints-save-christmas

So, I've purchased and downloaded the Season Pass, which includes "ENTER THE DOMINATRIX" and "How The Saints Saved Christmas". How do I actually access the content? I can't find a mission marker for these on the ship or in the world, and none of the menus in the game refer to these DLC packs. I know they're installed, since both packs show a star next to them in the DLC list; how do I actually access them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have the DLC installed, in your phone, on the "Quests" menu, will be two new quests.

If you select either of these quests, you'll be given the first waypoint for the DLC mission you picked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have access to your ship for the bonus content 'Enter the Dominatrix' DLC.