# Saints Row 4 DLC

Tags: saints-row-iv, saints-row-iv-saints-save-christmas

I'm replaying Saints Row 4 with "How the Saints saved Christmas" DLC. I've started a new game, and just escaped the simulation etc. I've heard that the DLC can be immediately started via a new quest after returning to the simulation, but I can't see any related quests.

I'm not planning on playing any further into the main campaign, I'm just wanting to play the DLC, so I may not be at a point where I can play it yet.

This is a similar question, but it does not answer my own question:

[How do I initiate the DLC missions in Saints Row 4?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/167912/how-do-i-initiate-the-dlc-missions-in-saints-row-4)

I can access my phone, but there are no quests related to the DLC; are there any prerequisites to beginning the DLC? Could it be installed incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried the solution offered in the question you've linked? Do you have access to your cell phone?

Comment: @JohnoBoy That's the link I have above, I've looked at the quest menu and there's three quests; main campaign, Kinzie's and Pierce's loyalty missions.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but did you guys actually read my question? The "duplicate" asked when it was available. I said I'm at that point, and I'm asking why it *isn't* available - e.g. bug, other requirements etc. I explicitly said that I'd read the "duplicate" and that it not answer my question.

Comment: While the two questions appear to be similar, they address two separate issues. In this case, it appears that you cannot access the DLC in the normal way. Therefore, I have voted to reopen this question.

Comment: @Thebluefish thank you, I'm sorry for any trouble that this may have caused

Answer (score 2):

Having recalled that I effectively jumped straight into the DLCs, with no partners unlocked or real progress made, I looked this up on the Steam forums.

> **Posting on a [Steam Forums](http://steamcommunity.com/app/206420/discussions/) post entitled ["How to access How The Saints Saved Christmas"](http://steamcommunity.com/app/206420/discussions/0/630800443554900602/), *[V]IdolNinja* writes:** How the Saints Save Christmas dlc unlocks after you get Telekinesis. You should get an unlock screen after completing the first Genki Mind Over Murder.

This makes the most sense, in review of my achievement log.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this.  I realized that I just did not notice the quest being available when I received telekinesis, but I did the CID recruitment mission directly afterwards and drew an incorrect conclusion.

Comment: Thankyou for making the effort to read my question, I'll mark this as the answer after I test it for myself (don't SR4 installed right now).